# Android Studio Flutter, Can't figure out how to save a change to a variable using a TextformField

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, textformfield

I'm trying to make a feature where a user can enter in a number into a TextFormField, and after they press the button it will set off an alarm after the user's specified number of minutes. The code below shows the idea of what I am trying to do. The problem I am having is that the variable `_valueAlarm` doesn't update when a new number is entered in the field. I was hoping that it would update in the `OnSaved` part in my `minAlarmFormField`. I have looked at multiple other threads about updating a variable in a TextFormField using things like keys but I don't understand how to implement it based off of what they are saying and reading key documentation(Assuming that is the problem). Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager/android_alarm_manager.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_ringtone_player/flutter_ringtone_player.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isOn = false;
  int alarmId = 1;
  var _controller = TextEditingController();
  var _valueAlarm = 0;
  var now = DateTime.now();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Alarm',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0,),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50.0),
          child: minAlarmFormField(context)),
          startButton()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField minAlarmFormField(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,

      validator: (value){
        if( value!.isEmpty || (double.parse(value) < 0 || double.parse(value) > 59)){
          return ('0-59');
        }
      },
      onSaved: (value) {
        _valueAlarm = value as int;
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'e.g.) 55',
        labelText: 'Minute',
      ),
    );
  }

  ElevatedButton startButton(){
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () async {
        print("alarm start at ${DateTime.now()}");
        print("minAlarm value is $_valueAlarm");
        await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
          Duration(minutes: _valueAlarm),
          alarmId,
          fireAlarm,
          exact: true,
          wakeup: true,
          );
        },
      child:const Text(
      'Start',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
      ),
    );
  }

}

void fireAlarm() {
  print('Alarm Fired at ${DateTime.now()}');
  FlutterRingtonePlayer.play(
    android: AndroidSounds.notification,
    ios: IosSounds.glass,
    looping: false,
    volume: 0.5,
    asAlarm: true,
  );
}
```

Comment: Use -> onChange() method for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use _controller.text instead:

[image]

The result:

[image]